# Webpack equivalent for browserify shiming(global) of already included modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, browserify, webpack

I am wondering what the webpack equivalent of browserify shiming is?

I develop a widget using npm and webpack which is included in another app. This other app already includes moment.js already in a script tag.

I don't want to bundle moment.js again in the widget bundle but still be able to use it. (`import moment from 'moment'`).

In browserify this was done with a `global:moment` statement. Does someone know the  webpack equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I put the following in my `webpack.config.js`:

```
externals: {
  'moment': 'moment',
},
```