# What is the webpack equivalent of -g in rollup?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, debian, rollupjs

I'm packaging d3-color module for debian. Since rollup is not packaged yet, I'd like to use webpack as bundler. d3-color package.json has the following command to build the umd module.

```
rollup --banner \"$(preamble)\" -f umd -g d3-color:d3 -n d3 -o build/d3-interpolate.js -- index.js"
```

I want to know how to convert *-g d3-color:d3* to webpack. I looked at [Webpack equivalent for browserify shiming(global) of already included modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33731430/webpack-equivalent-for-browserify-shimingglobal-of-already-included-modules) but that does not work.

https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-javascript/node-d3-interpolate.git/log/?h=webpack (packaging source)

Answer (score 0):

From https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/#externalize-lodash I tried this,

```
  externals: {
    'd3-color': {
      commonjs: 'd3-color',
      commonjs2: 'd3-color',
      amd: 'd3-color',
      root: '_'
    }
  }
```

and it seems to be working.